# Code will not work without CCLOG in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm currently working on a game that will randomly generate a dungeon for the player. This is made up of a whole heap of different methods being called from different files. I seem to have the code working to be able to calculate how much space is available on the other side of the door.

There is a catch however; the code only seems to work when I am outputting to the console using CCLOG. I wrote a good chunk of the code without testing and decided to then work through it in steps to see how the code worked (I figured I would just get it to run without bugs and next I will check my values).

After I had established that the code was successfully checking available space in each direction, while listing the locations it had checked, I decided that I would like to remove the CCLOG output. Unfortunately though, doing this caused the code to stop working.

```
//First check "forward"
bottom = CGPointMake(startLocation.x + forwardDirectionModifier.x, startLocation.y + forwardDirectionModifier.y);

top = bottom;

do
{
    currentLocation = CGPointMake(top.x + forwardDirectionModifier.x, top.y + forwardDirectionModifier.y);
    tileType = [tileCache getTileType:currentLocation];
    if (tileType == TileTypeFiller)
    {
        top = currentLocation;
        CCLOG(@"Top location is %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(top));
    }

} while (tileType == TileTypeFiller || top.y != 63);
```

This is a small snippet from the code; It is the section of code I think is most likely the issue. Essentially the problem is that if I comment out or delete the line `CCLOG(@"Top location is %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(top));` it will stop working.

Here are some more details:

- I have several little chunks of code like this, as long as I CCLOG in each one, it will be able to move to the next. If i were to comment out any of them, it would stop progress to the next chunk.
- I can change the CCLOG to output anything and it will still work, it just has to be there.
- I have tried cleaning the project.
- There are more CCLOG's that aren't used inside any loops and they can be removed without consequence.

Does anyone have a solution to this? As far as I can tell, whether I do or do not output something to the console,it shouldn't have an effect on whether or not the code will execute.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** At Ben Trengrove's suggestion, I am adding in further examples of where the CCLOG is being used.

This code immediately follows the previously listed code.

```
//Check left relative to door
farLeft = CGPointMake(startLocation.x + leftDirectionModifier.x, startLocation.y + leftDirectionModifier.y);

do
{
    currentLocation = CGPointMake(farLeft.x + leftDirectionModifier.x, farLeft.y + leftDirectionModifier.y);
    tileType = [tileCache getTileType:currentLocation];
    if (tileType == TileTypeFiller)
    {
        farLeft = currentLocation;
        CCLOG(@"Far Left location is %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(farLeft));
    }

} while (tileType == TileTypeFiller || farLeft.x !=0);

//Check forwards from far left
top2 = farLeft;

do
{
    currentLocation = CGPointMake(top2.x + forwardDirectionModifier.x, top2.y + forwardDirectionModifier.y);
    tileType = [tileCache getTileType:currentLocation];
    if (tileType == TileTypeFiller)
    {
        top2 = currentLocation;
        CCLOG(@"Top2 location is %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(top2));
    }

} while ((tileType == TileTypeFiller)|| (top2.y != 63));
```

Comment: I can't see any problem there with that CCLog, perhaps show some of the others.

Comment: describe 'it works' and 'it will stop working', what you expect, and what you are getting.

Comment: unless something really, really weird is going on, the logs can't be the problem.

Comment: I was thinking it might be something like if's without braces so when he comments out the log everything is changed

Comment: Could also be NSLog(@"%d", i++)

Comment: @YvesLeBorg When it works,the code will check a location, the function will find what type of tile exists at that location and if that location is a filler tile, that location becomes the new greatest value in that direction. This is repeated until the tile type returned is something other than a filler or the max x/y value is met in that direction. When I remove the CCLOG it seems like it is getting stuck in the loop forever.

Comment: @BenTrengrove I have updated my question to show some more of the code. If I include the first CCLOG, comment out the second and then leave the third one there, it will get through the first do while but doesn't seem to exit the second or reach the third.

Comment: i have used CCLOG too often to believe there is anything in the ones you show there that would cause a malfunction. I think that the conditions under which you run this code (with and without log) are the root cause of the malfunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem has now been solved, it seems that in part there was a fault in my logic.
Here is what I've done that now works:

```
do
{
    currentLocation = CGPointMake(top.x + forwardDirectionModifier.x, top.y + forwardDirectionModifier.y);
    tileType = [tileCache getTileType:currentLocation];
    if (tileType == TileTypeFiller)
    {
        top = currentLocation;
    }
    locationCount++;

} while ((tileType == TileTypeFiller) && (locationCount != 15));
CCLOG(@"Top location is %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(top));
```

The change is that I've switched to AND as opposed to OR. I also changed the second part of the while as I realised that due to my max room size, I never needed to check more than 15 locations in any given direction.

Thanks a lot to everyone that has helped. I'm still not entirely sure though how the use of CCLOG was somehow able to help get past a fault in logic but at least it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

What does your tile cache return as a tileType when there is no tile at currentLocation ? TileTypeFiller by any chance ?  if yes, you have an almost certain never ending loop there, under the right circumstances..

EDIT :

please add a line after the loop

```
CCLOG(@"");
```

and place a breakpoint on that line. See if the program stops there.

Comment: I have encountered the never ending loop before as I was only doing a "do while" for the tileType, which didn't cover it when I got past the last location (empty space doesn't have a tileType) so I added the check to see if we're past the last tile in the game. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: well, i'd be willing to bet that someComputedFloat != 63.0 will always be true.

Comment: The idea is that the while loop will exit when a tileType other than filler is met or the value being checked is 63. So far it is possible to exit the loop when the last condition is met, however that only happens with the log. I will look at the breakpoint idea, however I was previously using a breakpoint at the line `top2 = farLeft;` and it was reaching it(again, only when I used CCLOG).

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it makes no difference.
I put the `CCLOG(@"");` immediately after the loop and left the other CCLOG in and set the breakpoint. The point was met.
Next i tried commenting out the original CCLOG again, however this time the breakpoint was not met. Really seems like its execution has become conditional to me using CCLOG in the loop.

Comment: CGPoint farLeft, left, farRight, right, top, top2, bottom, currentLocation, forwardDirectionModifier, leftDirectionModifier, topLeft, bottomRight;

At the top of the function.